# Difference between a=b=class_name(value) and a=class_name(value) b=class_name(value) in python [not duplicate]

Tags: python, class, object, instance, repr

In the following code, if I use `tree = parent = node(leaf_1)`
the `tree` and `parent` are always having the same print result; whereas, if I change that line to `tree = node(leaf_1)` and `parent = node(leaf_1)`, then the `tree` and `parent` will not be the same.

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = []
    def __repr__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.value)+"\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__repr__(level+1)
        return ret
    def add(self, nod):
        self.children.append(node(nod))
leaf_1 = [1,4,3]
leaf_2 = [2,5,3]
leaf_3 = [4,4,3]

tree = parent = node(leaf_1) #### code 1
parent.add(leaf_2)
parent.add(leaf_3)
print(tree)
print(parent)
```

In above code, both `print` have the same output as follows:

```
output 1:
[1, 4, 3]
    [2, 5, 3]
    [4, 4, 3]
```

However, if I change `tree = parent = node(leaf_1)` to `tree = node(leaf_1)` and `parent = node(leaf_1)`, output:

```
output 2:
[1, 4, 3]

[1, 4, 3]
    [2, 5, 3]
    [4, 4, 3]
```

My **question**:

why the `tree = parent = node(leaf_1)` and  `tree = node(leaf_1); parent = node(leaf_1)` have different output?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you write `tree = parent = node(leaf_1)`, `tree` and `parent` point to the same `node`. With `tree = node(leaf_1)`, `parent = node(leaf_1)`, `tree` and `parent` point to two different `nodes`.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, another question, do you know why do I get error if I use `self.children.append(nod)` instead of `self.children.append(node(nod))` in the `add` method? the error is "TypeError: expected 0 arguments, got 1"

Comment: Your `leaf_1`, `leaf_2` and `leaf_3` are not `nodes`, they are normal `lists`. In your `__repr__` function you loop through children and then call `__repr__` on them. But then you are calling the `__repr__` function of `list` and not of `node` and you get the "expected 0 arguments" error. I guess you intended the `leafs` to be `nodes`. (BTW in general if you have a second question create a new post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `tree = parent = node(leaf_1)`, creates a single `node` object and assigns it to `tree` and `parent` and this `tree = node(leaf_1); parent = node(leaf_1)` created two different `node` objects and assigns them to `tree` and `parent` respectively.

---

```py
parent.add(leaf_2)
parent.add(leaf_3)
```

Here you are adding `leaf_2` and `leaf_3` only to `parent`. That may be the reason of output in second case.

Comment: Thanks @nobleknight, this is clear now. Another question, do you know why do I get error if I use `self.children.append(nod)` instead of `self.children.append(node(nod))` in the `add` method? the error is "TypeError: expected 0 arguments, got 1"? thanks!